# javascript, php, onchange select box not working

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have a form with two select boxes, I wish to live change the boxes without having to press the submit button.

This is the code I use:

```
    <script>

   $( document ).ready(function() {

       $('#provincie').live('change', function(event){
    if($(this).val() == '#provincie'){
        $("#result_div").empty()
    }else{
          var values = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "toevoegen.php",
            data: values,
            success: function(data){
                $("#result_div").empty().append(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                $("#result_div").empty().append('something went wrong');
            }
        });
    }
   });
});
</script>


<?php
    $select =
    "SELECT
            provincie
        FROM
            plaatsen
        GROUP BY
            provincie
        ";

$exec = mysql_query($select) or die ('Ojee, foutieve query!: '.mysql_error());

echo '<form id="provincies" method="post">';
    echo "<select id='provincie' name = 'provincie' onchange=\"this.form.submit()\">";                                          
    echo "<option value=''>Kies provincie</option>";

   while ($provincie = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$provincie['provincie'].'">'.$provincie['provincie'].'</option>';

            }
      echo "</select>";
      $provincies = $_POST['provincie'];
    ?>
    </select>
    <div id="result_div">
    Gekozen provincie: <?php echo $provincies; ?><br />
    </div>


<?php

   if(isset($_POST['provincie'])){
      $plaats_query =

        "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            plaatsen
        WHERE
            provincie = '".$_POST['provincie']."'
        GROUP BY
            plaats
        ORDER BY
            plaats ASC
            ";

        $plaats_result = mysql_query($plaats_query) or die ("FOUT: " . mysql_error());

        echo "<select id='plaatsnaam' name = 'plaatsnaam'>";
        echo "<option value=''>Kies plaatsnaam</option>";

        while($plaats = mysql_fetch_assoc($plaats_result))

          {
          echo "<option value='" . $plaats['stadid'] . "'>" . $plaats['plaats'] . "</option>";
          }
          echo "</select>";
}
$plaatsje_query =

        "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            plaatsen
        WHERE
            stadid = '".$_POST['plaatsnaam']."'
        GROUP BY
            plaats
        ORDER BY
            plaats ASC
            ";

        $plaatsje_result = mysql_query($plaatsje_query) or die ("FOUT: " . mysql_error());
        while($plaatsje = mysql_fetch_assoc($plaatsje_result))

$woonplaats = $plaatsje['plaats'];
$regiotje = $plaatsje['regio'];

$plaatsjes_query =

        "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            plaatsen
        WHERE
            stadid = '".$_POST['plaatsnaam']."'
        GROUP BY
            regio
        ORDER BY
            regio ASC
            ";

        $plaatsjes_result = mysql_query($plaatsjes_query) or die ("FOUT: " . mysql_error());
        while($plaatsjes = mysql_fetch_assoc($plaatsjes_result))

$regiotje = $plaatsjes['regio'];

?>
<br />

          <label for="categorie">Categorie selecteren *</label>
          <select id="categorie" name="categorie">
            <option value="">Selecteer de categorie</option>
            <?php
            while ($categorie = mysql_fetch_assoc($catexec)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$categorie['catid'].'">'.$categorie['catname'].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                var categorie = new LiveValidation('categorie');
                categorie.add( Validate.Presence );
            </script>
          <br class="clear" />

<fieldset>
          <label for="bedrijf">Naam bedrijf *</label>
          <input id="bedrijf" name="bedrijf" class="text" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
                    var bedrijf = new LiveValidation('bedrijf');
                    bedrijf.add(Validate.Presence);
                  </script>
                  <br class="clear" />
          <label for="contactpersoon">Contactpersoon</label>
          <input id="contactpersoon" name="contactpersoon" class="text" />
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" class="text" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
                    var email = new LiveValidation('email');
                    email.add(Validate.Email );
                  </script>
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="website">Website</label>
          <input id="website" name="website" class="text" />
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="telefoon">Telefoonnummer *</label>
          <input id="telefoon" name="telefoon" class="text" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
                var telefoon = new LiveValidation('telefoon');
                telefoon.add( Validate.Presence );
            </script>
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="fax">Fax</label>
          <input id="fax" name="fax" class="text" />
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="straat">Straat *</label>
          <input id="straat" name="straat" class="text" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
                var straat = new LiveValidation('straat');
                straat.add( Validate.Presence );
            </script>
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="postcode">Postcode *</label>
          <input id="postcode" name="postcode" class="text" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
                var postcode = new LiveValidation('postcode');
                postcode.add( Validate.Presence );
            </script>
          <br class="clear" />
          <input type="hidden" name="transno" id="transno" value="<?php echo $n; ?>" />
          <br class="clear" />
          <label for="kvk"><abbr title="Kamer van Koophandel Nummer" lang="NL">KvK</abbr> nummer *</label>
          <input id="kvk" name="kvk" class="text" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
                var kvk = new LiveValidation('kvk');
                kvk.add( Validate.Presence );
                kvk.add( Validate.Numericality );
            </script>
          <br class="clear" />
          <br />
          <label for="beschrijving">Beschrijving bedrijf</label>
          <textarea name="beschrijving" id="beschrijving" onKeyPress="return charLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return characterCount(this)" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
          <p class="charcounter"><strong><span id="charCount">500</span></strong> karakters beschikbaar.</p>


<input type="submit" value="Verzenden">
</form>
```

The code works, but only after pressing submit its is that I can choose the cities out of the previously chosen province.

I need it to live change, how do I fix this ??

I am a starter in programming and really stuck right now.

Thanks in advance

Klaas

Comment: if($(this).val() == '#provincie')) {} are you sure the value has # in it? try if($(this).val() == 'provincie')) {}

Comment: tries removing the #, but that does not work, leaves results out of boxes after submitting

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

       $('#provincie').on('change', function(event){
    if($(this).val() == '#provincie'){
        $("#result_div").empty()
    }else{
        var values = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "toevoegen.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            success: function(data){
                $("#result_div").empty().append(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                $("#result_div").empty().append('something went wrong');
            }
        });
    }
   });
});
```

Hope it will work for you. If it didnt please let me know.

Comment: Hello Tristup,tried your suggestion, but instead of the second selectbox opening I get the result_div with the something went wrong message.

Comment: Form and Select Box have same ID, Please change the id for form

Comment: You don't need document.ready, just place the script before the ending of body tag

Comment: That is true but the DOM says to load the script when its ready

Comment: after changing the form id :                                       var values = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

Comment: Altered script rules and form name, still the result_div with error message comes up instead of second box.

Comment: Also tried calling the value in the error div by this statement: $provincies = $_POST['provincie'];   and calling it by <?php echo $provincies; ?>   this works only after submitting the first selectbox, then the error message appers, with the result of the first selectbox (<?php echo $provincies; ?>) and also the second selectbox appears.

Comment: @ Klass Postma, As you have the form and the Selectbox id same the Form Submit was working for you. So please try in that way.

Comment: Changed it back, still need to press submit before second box works

Comment: You need to do few things step wise.                              1. Document.ready 2. Form ID Change 3. var values = $(this).closest('form').serialize();                                   if still it not worked please paste the new code after dong the changes.

Comment: Altered code with your changes has been put in original question.

Comment: Something Went wrong is showing onchange of selectbox?

Comment: Please try with live function instead of on function " $('#provincie').live "

Comment: changed it to $('#provincie').live('change', function(event){ ..... now the result_div does not appear, but I still need to press submitt instead of onchange working live.   I am done for today, be back tomorrow.

Comment: hmmm...  just tested this      echo "<select id='provincie' name = 'provincie' onchange=\"this.form.submit()\">";   now it changes, but not quite how I wished.  This alteration should not be necessary and been done in script part instead of form select ???

Comment: Hello, I have finished the form and completed the inserts for db.  I only have a problem left now.  As soon as I select the first box (provincie) an insert into database is done.  The database insert needs to be done after making 3 selections from boxes and filling out several other boxes and press submitt.  Any ideas on how to fix this ???

Comment: please try bind method instead of live method. If it didnt work I will give u a solution on javascript and jquery

Comment: Tried with bind method also, I still get 3 inserts in database, 2 blankes, and after submitting the complete form I get the third insert with all the data.  been trying several methods found here on stackoverflow.  I am confused right now

Comment: <select id='provincie' name = 'provincie' onchange=\"submitDataAjax()\"> Here submitDataAjax() is a javascript method and put the ajax code inside into it. And also I find that You cahanged every